# Async post Infragistics data grid check box

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

How do I make an asynchronous postback in Infragistics data grid check box?

Comment: Which one of the 3 grids? Ultra? Web? WebHierarchical?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kinda confusing. If you ment to update only once column that is not possible and you have to put the grid into update panel. If you want to make postback on checkbox column checked/unchecked put it in  update panel and catch the event of the checkbox where you  call the update method.